# Snort on Raspberry Pi w/ Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux, curl

So after not being able to `pacman -S snort` I tried downloading snort directly from aur and running `makepkg -acs --asroot`

I'm currently getting an error message:
 0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid

I've looked through the PKGBUILD and snort.install to look for somewhere to put --no-check-certificate, I've attempted to update certificates and a plethora of other fixes that haven't work.

Anyone else had this issue and resolved it or know of a work around?

Comment: Is the time and date correct on your Pi?